# Force.com IDE in brand new eclipse fails to Add/Remove Metadata Components (on specific Orgs)

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

**OUTLINE**

When I want to select the Metadata types for the project, I only get the error:

> Unable to open custom component selection dialog. Reason: An
>   unexpected error has occurred.

[image]

I don't know if it matters, but I have multiple JDKs and JREs installed.

**DETAILS**

Just installed eclipse 4.6.2 (fresh, clean, empty) just for the force.com plugin, nothing else:

[image]

Installed fresh force.com plugin:

[image]

Creating new force.com project with all setting defaul: it works, project there and metadata, too:

[image]

Now if I rightclick the project > Force.com > Add/Remove Metadata Components... and in the next Popup I click the button [Add/Remove] like this:

[image]

The progressbar advances until nearly it's end and I got these Error popups:

[image]

[image]

Tried this on a different eclipse version 4.5 and got exactly the same issue. I have multiple JDK, JRE installed.

---

**Error Log 1**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

com.salesforce.ide.core
Error
Sat Jan 14 16:44:59 CET 2017
ERROR [2017-01-14 16:44:59,571] (ProjectProjectContentComposite.java:widgetDefaultSelected:296) - Unable to open custom component selection dialog

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.salesforce.ide.core.internal.utils.PackageManifestDocumentUtils.getPackageNode(PackageManifestDocumentUtils.java:157)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.getComponentTypesFromCache(PackageManifestController.java:1002)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.createModel(PackageManifestController.java:827)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.updateManifest(PackageManifestController.java:174)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.getEnabledCompTypeTreeNodes(PackageManifestController.java:439)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestTree$ManifestContentProvider.getElements(PackageManifestTree.java:690)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1001)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:701)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getRawChildren(TreeViewer.java:341)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:907)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getSortedChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:621)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTreeViewer.java:817)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:795)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:766)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1538)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:772)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$1(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1523)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1458)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer.preservingSelection(CheckboxTreeViewer.java:409)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestTree$PackageManifestTreeViewer.preservingSelection(PackageManifestTree.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1517)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:286)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1696)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestTree.updateTree(PackageManifestTree.java:1693)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.initialize(ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.java:116)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.<init>(ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.java:72)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.createDialogArea(ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.create(ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectProjectContentComposite$8.widgetDefaultSelected(ProjectProjectContentComposite.java:294)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectProjectContentComposite$8.widgetSelected(ProjectProjectContentComposite.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.handlers.OpenProjectContentPropertiesHandler.execute(OpenProjectContentPropertiesHandler.java:31)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor195.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:433)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:454)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$3.handleEvent(AbstractContributionItem.java:482)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

---

**Error Log 2**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

com.salesforce.ide.core
Error
Sat Jan 14 16:44:57 CET 2017
ERROR [2017-01-14 16:44:57,117] (PackageManifestController.java:loadAll:502) - Unable to refresh file metadata


java.lang.NullPointerException

at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1192)
at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1186)
at com.salesforce.ide.core.remote.metadata.FileMetadataExt$1.compare(FileMetadataExt.java:37)
at com.salesforce.ide.core.remote.metadata.FileMetadataExt$1.compare(FileMetadataExt.java:1)
at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:239)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
at com.salesforce.ide.core.remote.metadata.FileMetadataExt.sort(FileMetadataExt.java:418)
at com.salesforce.ide.core.remote.metadata.FileMetadataExt.getFilePropertiesMap(FileMetadataExt.java:322)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController$1.run(PackageManifestController.java:298)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:481)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:242)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:1074)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.updateCache(PackageManifestController.java:295)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.loadAll(PackageManifestController.java:486)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.updateManifest(PackageManifestController.java:173)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestController.getEnabledCompTypeTreeNodes(PackageManifestController.java:439)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestTree$ManifestContentProvider.getElements(PackageManifestTree.java:690)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1001)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:701)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getRawChildren(TreeViewer.java:341)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:907)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getSortedChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:621)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTreeViewer.java:817)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:795)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:766)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1538)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:772)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$1(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1523)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1458)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer.preservingSelection(CheckboxTreeViewer.java:409)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestTree$PackageManifestTreeViewer.preservingSelection(PackageManifestTree.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1517)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:286)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1696)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.packagemanifest.PackageManifestTree.updateTree(PackageManifestTree.java:1693)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.initialize(ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.java:116)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.<init>(ProjectCustomComponentsComposite.java:72)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.createDialogArea(ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.create(ProjectCustomComponentsDialog.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectProjectContentComposite$8.widgetDefaultSelected(ProjectProjectContentComposite.java:294)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.wizards.project.ProjectProjectContentComposite$8.widgetSelected(ProjectProjectContentComposite.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
at com.salesforce.ide.ui.handlers.OpenProjectContentPropertiesHandler.execute(OpenProjectContentPropertiesHandler.java:31)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor195.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:433)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:454)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$3.handleEvent(AbstractContributionItem.java:482)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

---

**Warning Log (directly before the error)**

```
 eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400

    java.version=1.8.0_91
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

    com.salesforce.ide.core
    Warning
    Sat Jan 14 17:13:57 CET 2017
     WARN [2017-01-14 17:13:57,929] (Utils.java:loadDocument:807) - Unable to load document: D:\Pool\eclipse-projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\heim@xe301.elastify.eu\com.salesforce.ide.core\packageCache.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: Using Window -> Show View -> Other... -> General -> Error Log in Eclipse will give you a view where the drill-down may offer more detail such as a stack trace that may help.

Comment: @KeithC thanks for pointing me there. I added the two error logs. Unfortunately I can't figure what the problem is.

Comment: Right off the bat, look at the `java.lang.NullPointerException at`... in Error Log 1 about 13 lines down. It appears it can't open or parse the manifest package.

Comment: In the meantime I found, that it's org-specific. On a black empty Org it works. But for nearly all of my used Orgs, it fails. There must be something with a name of a piece of metadata or with an installed package.

Comment: I also added an additional warning happening right before the error happens. Its about packageCache.xml

Comment: FYI this is open source e.g. https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/644dd3189404b1b1fbea6313d7dd13883b023cec/com.salesforce.ide.core/src/com/salesforce/ide/core/internal/utils/PackageManifestDocumentUtils.java#L157 so you can work back from that if you have the willpower.

Comment: My first immediate thought is that you managed to grab a copy of the IDE that is using version 39.0 (Spring 17) and it only works on the one sandbox that you have that's running Spring 17). It's only a theory, but could you check and see if that's the case?

Comment: @sfdcfox unfortunately plugin is v38 and orgs are v38, too. Also it must be something in the Orgs, because blank orgs do work. So I would rule everything from the local stack out. However my older versions of eclipse with plugin v35 work on all of my orgs. So there is something org specific not matching to a change in the plugin since v35. Could be my managed packages. I already found that pipe characters in Package Names are causing warnings. That I've fixed already: it reduced the warnings from about 100 to 10, but I still got other warnings and the 2 erros. But something like that it is.

Comment: this happened to me just last week and it was org specific - see open Issue https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/212. Unfortunately, why remains a mystery to me

Comment: Ditto for Eclipse 4.7.1a (Oxygen) with a Summer'17 sandbox (version 40).

Answer (score 9):

I found a **workaround** for this issue: Instead of using the UI to Add/Remove Metadata Components you can do that editing the file /src/package.xml

If you use defaults, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

Now if you want to add e.g. Flexipages you simply add inside the Package-tag

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>FlexiPage</name> 
</types>
```

Make sure to "Work online", save the file and "Refresh from Server" and you will get the Flexipages into the UI. If you need other Metadata types, just add them the same way. To figure out the Names, just review : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm - most of them should work.

Bottom line: for my taste this Workaround is even faster and better than using the UI.

Comment: Great! Also works for Eclipse 4.7.1a (Oxygen) with a Summer'17 sandbox (version 40).

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me. I want to add Reports to the list of objects because I need to do a search for a filter occurrence. The report folder just doesn't appear. Does anybody know why? or does anybody have another solution?
I had a look at the Project settings again and there it doesn't show up after adding the lines in the package file. I also restarted Eclipse and looked at all the settings files for the project in the workspace with no success.

Comment: @VikingWicki this is due to Report folders. Try to add FolderName/* or explicitly state each individual Report path. Spaces and special chars in Folder or name need to be url-encoded. Ask  a separate question on how to retrieve Reports via package.xml and/or url-encoding in that context.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the problem is in Eclipse working with Force.com IDE v38.0. I tried going back to v37.0 and it works fine.

First remove v38.0 (via Help->Installation Details). You can then download version 37.0 from https://developer.salesforce.com/media/force-ide/eclipse45 (uncheck "Show Only Latest Versions").

Comment: not able to install v37 with eclipse oxygen. It's installing version 38 even though I have asked for version 37.